# clean method not working for URLField

Tags: django

I'm working on something where I require users to enter URLs. I then realized that most users don't prepend 'http://' when writing a URL and then I decided to use a clean method. After checking lots of places for URLField clean methods, I came up with this:

```
from django import forms
from rango.models import Category, Page

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter category name")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    # Create an inline class to provide extra information about the form
    class Meta:
        # Provide the association between a model form and a model
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the title of the page")
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the url of the page", initial="http://")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')

        # If url is not empty and doesn't start with http://, prepend it
        if url and not url.startswith('http://'):
            url = 'http://' + url
            cleaned_data['url'] = url

            return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        # Provide association between model form and model
        model = Page
        # What fields do we want to include or exclude from our form?
        exclude = ('category',)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as I still get the invalid url error. Is there something I'm missing? And if yes, what?

Comment: What is your input? And what do you get/expect? And what does "super().clean()"?

Comment: @Heri assuming I want to enter www.google.com, If I enter the url that way, I get an error that http:// is missing. So I am looking for a function to prepend 'http://' automatically

Comment: And if you enter http://www.google.com/ it doesn't raise a validation error?

Comment: @lmr2391 I don't want it to raise a validation error

Comment: If the validate function of your form raises an ValidationError this exception is caught somewhere up the call stake and the message is saved to form.errors. So you don't get a 500 server error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't enter a scheme for the URL (e.g. `http://`), then Django will default to `http://`. Therefore you don't need the `clean_url` method and can remove it.

The problem is that because Django renders the form with `type=url`, your browser is also validating the input. Because the browser thinks the input is invalid, the form is never submitted to Django.

One option would be to change the input to a `TextInput`, which would stop your browser from validating it as a URL.

```
url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput, help_text="Please enter the url of the page")
```

Another option would be to add `novalidate` to the form tag, but this would turn off browser validation for the entire form.

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
  {{ form }}
</form>
```

Comment: TextInput worked great, thanks. I'm just leaving reference to Docs: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) HTML5 input types and browser validation.  In my case, since I only needed the widget I added this in the form: `widgets={'url':TextInput()}`. TextInput imported from django.forms.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only validating one field, you shouldn't do that in the forms clean method, but in the `clean_url`-method. For me, this is working fine:

```
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data.get('url')
        if not url.startswith('http://'):
            url = 'http://' + url
        return url
```